# How to type text in wxPython FilePickerCtrl text box without getting an error?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I have a wxPython-based program where I create a file selection interface using FilePickerCtrl:

```
class MainFrame (wx.Frame):
    ...
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.filePicker = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, path = wx.EmptyString,
                                            message = "Select a file", wildcard = "*.m",
                                            pos = wx.DefaultPosition,
                                            size = wx.DefaultSize,
                                            style = wx.FLP_OPEN|wx.FLP_USE_TEXTCTRL)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_FILEPICKER_CHANGED, self.onFilePicker, 
                  id = self.filePicker.GetId())
    ...
    def onFilePicker(self, event):
        self.resetOnOpen(event)
        path = self.filePicker.GetPath()
        self.openFile(event, path)
        self.modifyHistory(event, path)
```

The button to select a file works fine, and I can select a file as expected. But as soon as I type even a single character in the text box next to the button, I get an exception: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`.  It appears that it's trying to find the file immediately, rather than waiting for the user to finish typing a path. (This happens on macOS 10.13, in case the OS is relevant.)

What is the proper way to let the user type a path in the box (if they prefer to type a path instead of clicking the file browsing button)?

I'm new to wxPython and obviously doing something wrong here, but can't seem to find an example of how to do this the right way.

Answer (score 1):

At least on Linux, the `wx.FLP_USE_TEXTCTRL` causes an event to fire for each key depression and I suppose that it is the same for other operating systems.
Ensure that you `import os` then change your `onFilePicker`  routine to check for the files existence.

```
def onFilePicker(self, event):
    self.resetOnOpen(event)
    path = self.filePicker.GetPath()
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        return
    self.openFile(event, path)
    self.modifyHistory(event, path)
```